# find-tag: Build a new TAGS file if it does not already exist

Tags: tags

I prefer to use the older version of `find-tag`, instead of the `xref` library.  I wrote a function to build the tag database, but I'm having trouble locating a good place to plug it in.  The default behavior when a TAGS file cannot be located is for `visit-tags-table-buffer` to generate an error message **"File %s does not exist"**.  By the time we get to that message, however, it is the end of the function and too late to build a new tags file.  I would like to do this without breaking `visit-tags-table-buffer`.

**Q**:  Where can I plug-in `tags-build` so that I can call `find-tag` and be on my merry way with a new TAGS file if one does not already exist?

```lisp
(defun tags-build ()
"Build the TAGS datbase and set the default `tags-file-name'."
(interactive)
  (let ((default-directory (file-name-as-directory (expand-file-name
                             (read-directory-name ".../src directory:  ")))))
    (set-process-sentinel
      (start-process "build-tags" nil
        "/bin/bash" "-c" "find . -iname \"*.c\" -or -iname \"*.h\" | xargs etags")
      `(lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
        (setq-default tags-file-name (expand-file-name "TAGS" ,default-directory))
        (message "tags-file-name:  %s" tags-file-name)
        tags-file-name)))))
```

Comment: Try advising `find-tag` itself and reimplement the tags file finding logic yourself in the advice. Shouldn't take too long.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/redguardtoo/counsel-etags

It has everything you need.

Comment: The library you suggested relies upon `(require 'xref nil t)`, which is something that I wish to avoid.  Other users, however, undoubtedly enjoy it.  It also relies upon a ton of stuff written by abo-abo (not built-in to Emacs), which is fine, but it just adds a whole layer of extra libraries and complication that seems unnecessary for this simple feature of adding a TAGS file if it does not already exist when calling `find-tag`.

Comment: `(require 'xref nil t)` means xref is OPTIONAL. The core functionalities are not dependent on xref