# How to programmatically extract path to etags executable

Tags: files, build

**Q**:  Assuming that we open Emacs with a path to `../Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs`, how can we programmatically extract the path to `etags` located at `../Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/etags`.  [The location of `Emacs.app` will vary.]

I want to build my own TAGS index for certain files from the Emacs source code that I am tinkering with in a project directory containing only those files.  Here is link to the *draft* function that I am using to build tags:  [find-tag: Build a new TAGS file if it does not already exist](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/36735/2287)

OSX comes with an outdated version of `etags` located at `/usr/bin/etags`.  I have recently learned that the outdated version of `etags` fails to index a ton of stuff in the current source code used to build Emacs.  That discovery, combined by a lesson from Eli Z. over on reddit (i.e., calling `make tags`), led me to the command line `../emacs/lib-src/etags`.  The `etags` executable that is used in Emacs 26 and the current version of the master branch is superior in terms of its ability to properly index the source code.  When calling `make install` (assuming Emacs was configured `--with-ns`), a packaged Emacs is created with a folder/package called `Emacs.app`.  I am making a leap by assuming that the executable located at `../Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/etags` is the same as found in the source code tree `../emacs/lib-src/etags`.  [If that assumption is wrong, please let me know.]

While the normal location of packaged applications ending in `.app` (on OSX) is in `/Applications`, I place them in other locations.  And, I have several versions of Emacs strewn about on my hard drive that I use periodically for different reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `invocation-directory` contains the directory in which the Emacs executable was found, so you can use

```
(file-truename (expand-file-name "bin/etags" invocation-directory))
```

See also the question [Can Emacs detect the path of its executable?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/6010/11725).